# How to read word by word from an array of char?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to make a program that reads a line from a text file, tinkers with it, and prints words to another text file that consist of even number of characters. I get a line by susing "fgets" and store it into an array of chars. But then how read from it word by word? ("Word" - is a stream of characters except spaces).

Thanks.

Comment: Consider first coding a sample of what you think may work.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and then base on the example below:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at [sscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). It takes as parameter a string / array of characters and reads from it what ever you describe in the format string. For a word you could use `%s` and check the result that it is not a punctuation or what ever you define as word.

Answer (score 0):

To read from files you can use `fscanf(file,"%s",cString)` it will do the trick. To answer question in title, you can use `fscanf(cStringSource,"%s",cString)`.

To read word by word you just need to simply put into a loop.

Referece: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf.

There is also something called `strtok`.